# Getting error while using env variables as ConfigService in NestJs

Tags: environment-variables, nestjs, nestjs-config

i'm using nestjs for project i have no issue using "@nestjs/config" before version 1.1.2 but when i created new one while copy paste from my old source code into my new one especially in main.ts it gives me error **Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.** when i passed string **LISTENING_PORT** into get function of configService but it worked in my old project what's the problem and how to solve this problem? thanks in advance.
here's my sample code

```
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as helmet from 'helmet';
import { CustomExceptionFilter } from './exceptions/custom-exception.filter';
import { CustomValidationPipe } from './pipes/custom-validation.pipe';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  app.use(helmet());
  app.useGlobalPipes(new CustomValidationPipe());
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new CustomExceptionFilter(configService));
  const listeningPort = configService.get('LISTENING_PORT');
  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('API Documentation')
    .setDescription('API description')
    .setVersion('0.1')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
  await app.listen(listeningPort);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: You have to provide more sample code to show whats going on here. Nobody knows what is happening inside your ConfigService.

Comment: The code you provided should work. I am using the same thing it's working fine for me. Maybe check your validation and configuration files.

Comment: Like i mentioned before it worked in my old project but when i created new and the version of config 1.1.2 not working. What version of your config?

Comment: i just try install again the nestjs/config and it already changed to 1.1.3 and now worked. the problem was in version 1.1.2

Comment: You can add an answer if you resolved it instead of editing solved in the title

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm using version 2.2.0!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed on @nestjs/config version 1.1.3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).